# Why node in heap data structure in many types has only two children?

Tags: data-structures, heap

From the wiki

> The maximum number of children each node can have depends on the type of heap, but in many types it is at most two, which is known as a binary heap.

I can't understand why in many types the node in heap at most has only two children? Why three children or four children and so on is not common? Thanks~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true that most types of heap have at most two children per node, but it is true that the binary heap -- which *does* have at most two children per node -- is the most commonly implemented type.  It's the most commonly implemented type because it is simple, cache-friendly, and memory-efficient.

The data structures used for binary heaps *could* be used with a different number of children per node.  The common operations in an *x*-ary heap would still take **O(log N)** time, if we consider **x** to be constant.  To decide on the best **x**, however, we have to let it vary, and in that case common operations take **O(x * log N / log x)** time.

To determine the most efficient number of children per node, we can choose *x* to minimize the factor **x/log x**.

If you plot that you can see that the best number of children per node is actually 3 (the minimum is at x=e, but we require an integer):

[image]

... but the difference between 2 and 3 is not significant, and the code is simpler using 2 children per node, so that is the common practice.

Comment: But the difference in actual running time between 2 and 3 is pretty significant. My tests show a 10% to 20% speedup going from a binary heap to a 3-heap. Mostly because the 3-heap is more cache-friendly than the binary heap.

Comment: @JimMischel good for you for actually testing!  10-20 percent matches the plot quite well.  I admit that you could consider that significant under some circumstances.

Comment: How do you determine `cache friendliness`?

Comment: @AdityaGupta it's a matter of how many blocks of memory will have to be read into the processor cache on average.  Using less memory, using memory that is contiguous, or using the same memory or nearby memory for many operations, all help reduce the number blocks read into cache.

Comment: Aah. So, when I traverse down a n-ary tree, n children data is loaded in cache. Is that so? But we won't be needing this data later anyway, because we move down further into the tree. How is it beneficial?

Comment: @AdityaGupta Because the next time you traverse down the tree for the *other* nearby children, they will *already* be in the cache.  Also the top few levels will be in the same block, and will be loaded into the cache all at once.

Comment: Ah Ok. Thank you